# Clarify steps to add a language variant to Stanza

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like to add a non-standard variant of a language already supported by Stanza. It should be named differently from the standard variety included in the common distribution of Stanza. I could use a modification of the corpus for training the AI, since the changes are mostly morphological rather than syntactical, but how many steps would I need to take in order to make a new language variety for Stanza from this background? I don't understand what data are input and what are output in the process of adding a new language in the web documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to add a different set of processors rather than a whole new language.  The difference being that other steps of the pipeline will still work the same, right?  NER models, for example.

If that's the case, if you can follow the steps to retrain the current models, you should be able to then replace the input data with your morphological updates.

I suggest filing an issue on github if you encounter difficulties in the process.  It will be a lot easier to back & forth there.

Times when we would actually recommend a whole new language are when 1) it's actually a new language or 2) it uses a different character set - think different writing systems for ZH or for Punjabi, if we had any Punjabi models